# unable to delete ec2-stack created using cloud formation template

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am unable to delete a ec2-stack that i have created using cloud formation. Reason is i manually terminated ec2-instance before running delete stack.
Is there a work around to delete the stack forcefully?

Comment: What is the error message showing in cloudformation while you tried to delete the stack ?

Comment: What resources is it showing as Not Deleted?

Comment: After deleting Elastic Network Interface (ENI) i am able to delete the ec2-stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually deleting resources will not be a cause for being unable to delete a CloudFormation stack.

You will need to examine the list of resources that it says are not yet deleted. The cause is typically due to an **Elastic Network Interface (ENI)** that is still attached to a VPC. Many different services can create ENIs.

Click **Network Interfaces** in the EC2 console to see if this is causing the problem.